# Getting timezone from dateutil.parser.parse in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-dateutil

Trying to parse the datetime string with timezone info and get the utc offset

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as parse_date
s = '2017-08-28 06:08:20,488 CDT'
dt = parse_date(s)
print(dt.utcoffset())  # prints `None`
```

Why is utcoffset returning `None` rather than `-5` as offset?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=utcoffset#datetime.datetime.utcoffset):

> If tzinfo is None, returns None

In your code, `dt.tzinfo` is `None`, so the timezone information was not parsed by `parse_date` into the `dt`. Your datetime `dt` is "naive" (has no timezone information).

As per the [dateutil docs](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse), You can pass your own timezone information to `parse_date` as either a `tzoffset` or `tzfile`:

```
tzinfos = {"CDT": -21600}
dt = parse_date('2017-08-28 06:08:20 CDT', tzinfos=tzinfos)
dt.tzinfo #tzoffset('CDT', -21600)

from dateutil import tz
tzinfos = {"CDT": tz.gettz('US/Central')}
dt = parse_date('2017-08-28 06:08:20 CDT', tzinfos=tzinfos)
dt.tzinfo #tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central')
```

Or you can encode the timezone offset into the string:

```
dt = parse_date('2017-08-28 06:08:20-06:00')
dt.tzinfo #tzoffset(None, -21600)
```