# ValueError: "time data %r does not match format %r"

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, strptime

I'm trying to parse time using `strptime`:

```
t = datetime.strptime('2024-08-21T11:00:00 EDT', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z')
```

This code works for me in GMT+4, but it fails in GMT-9:

```
ValueError: time data '2024-08-21T11:00:00 EDT' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What "it fails in GMT-9" means? Fails if python runs on  that TZ?

Comment: Please show the string it does work for. Also, why does the title have %r but that's not part of your code?

Comment: I use same sting for testing. The only difference is that I change system time zone.

Comment: If you don't want to rely in `%Z` to work *sometimes*, you basically have to define to which time zone an abbreviation maps ("time zone" in the sense of an identifier from the [iana db](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)). [Example using dateutil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45988363/10197418) - however, I don't suggest you need dateutil for this; writing a function that applies such a mapping is relatively simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to python docs [strptime() only accepts certain values for %Z](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail)

> strptime() only accepts certain values for %Z:
> any value in time.tzname for your machine’s locale
> the hard-coded values UTC and GMT

> So someone living in Japan may have JST, UTC, and GMT as valid values, but probably not EST. It will raise ValueError for invalid values.

Testing locally

```
TZ="+4" python3 -c "import time; print(time.tzname)"
TZ="+4" python3 -c "import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.strptime('2024-08-21T11:00:00 EDT', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z'))"
```

Results

```
('', '')
ValueError: unconverted data remains: EDT
```

For a supported TZ

```
TZ="US/Eastern" python3 -c "import time; print(time.tzname)"
('EST', 'EDT')
TZ="US/Eastern" python3 -c "import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.strptime('2024-08-21T11:00:00 EDT', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z'))"
2024-08-21 11:00:00
```

Even error string changes for some TZ. `America/Los_Angeles` returns error as reported by OP.

```
 TZ="America/Los_Angeles" python3 -c "import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.strptime('2024-08-21T11:00:00 EDT', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z'))"

ValueError: time data '2024-08-21T11:00:00 EDT' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z'
```

Fails anyway even if tzname has values

```
TZ="America/Los_Angeles" python3 -c "import time; print(time.tzname)"
('PST', 'PDT')
```

Comment: another important thing to notice here is that even if `%Z` "accepts" the time zone name abbreviation, it doesn't actually set the time zone in the resulting datetime object. The object is still [naive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that timezone support (`%Z`) in Python's `strptime()` relies on the underlying C library, which varies between different systems and might not recognize certain timezone abbreviations like 'EDT'.

You can try to work that around by handling TZ separately. First parse the timestamp without TZ part, then manually adjust the result. Alternatively, use [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) or other libs that can have a broader and more up-to-date database of timezones.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def parse_datetime_with_tz(datetime_tz_str):
    # Split the input string into datetime and timezone parts
    datetime_str, tz_str = datetime_tz_str.rsplit(' ', 1)

    # Parse the datetime part
    dt = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

    # TZ offests. Add more if needed 
    tz_offsets = {
        'EDT': -4,
    }

    tz_offset_hours = tz_offsets.get(tz_str, 0)
    tz_offset = timedelta(hours=tz_offset_hours)

    # Adjust the datetime for the timezone
    adjusted_dt = dt + tz_offset

    return adjusted_dt


timestamp = '2024-08-21T11:00:00 EDT'
parsed_dt = parse_datetime_with_tz(timestamp, timezone)
print(parsed_dt)
```